# MySQL count value in several columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL containing student grades. I would like to issue a single SQL query that would count a particular Grade from all columns, e.g

```
adNumber |Eng | Kis| Math| Phys| chem
1254     | A  | B  | B   | A   | D
2147     | B  | A  | A   | A   | C
3241     | D  | A  | C   | A   | E
```

I would like to get something like below:

```
Eng| kIS| Math | Phys | chem
1  | 2  |  1   |   3  |  0
```

When i issue statement to count "A" from all the columns. I will appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case  when  or an if  and one select

```
    select sum(case when Eng  = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Eng
        , sum(case when Kis  = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Kis
        , sum(case when Math  = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Math
        , sum(case when Phys  = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Phys
        , sum(case when Chem  = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Chem
    from Grades
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with subqueries

```
select 
    (Select count(*) from Grades where Eng = 'A') as Eng,
    (Select count(*) from Grades where Kis = 'A') as Kis,
    (Select count(*) from Grades where Math = 'A') as Math,
    (Select count(*) from Grades where Phys = 'A') as Phys,
    (Select count(*) from Grades where Chem = 'A') as Chem
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select sum(case when Eng = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Eng,
       sum(case when Kis = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Kis,
       sum(case when Math = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Math,
       sum(case when Phys = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Phys,
       sum(case when chem = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) chem
from Grades
```